# Oldest laptop to have App Store

Tags: mac, ipod-touch

My sons have iBook G4 laptops and are wanting to upgrade to a Mac that has App Store and iTunes so they can manage their iPods. Can someone please tell me what is the oldest laptop to have those capabilities?

Comment: Do they need the iTunes Store (for iPod touch apps) or the Mac App Store (for Mac apps)?

Answer (score 2):

The first appearance of the Mac App Store was 10.6.6 Snow Leopard.

Any Intel-based Mac will accommodate Snow Leopard. A list of Intel-based Macs can be found [here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_processor/) and at Apple's detailed [system build versions for Intel Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159). So the original MacBook Pro from February 2006 would be the oldest portable that can run the Mac App Store.

Depending on which iOS device they have, you might need Lion or even Mountain Lion to run a version of iTunes for some newer devices like the iPad mini or iPhone 5.

Comment: And you must update Snow Leopard to 10.6.8 after you install it. The App Store feature does not appear in any lower version of 10.6.x

Comment: Actually it appeared with the 10.6.6 update, 10.6.8 is just the most common way to enable it these days.

Comment: Yes, I omitted that because I presumed anyone installing SL would be installing the latest revision, but indeed, this is all true. Thanks for clarifying.